# Undefined reference during linking with DUMB and Allegro

Tags: compilation, linker, mingw, libraries, allegro

Ive been up for 10 hours trying to figure out this. Ive tried out a bunch of different libraries to try to get ogg or mp3 files to play with allegro 4. I downloaded DUMB library and copied the include and lib files to mingw respective places (i use codeblocks).
What is the correct way to install a library to my compiler? 
here is my code so far..

```
#include <allegro.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <aldumb.h>


#include "CUSTOM_FUNCTIONS_HEADER.h"
#include "status_screen_functions_header.h"

#define WHITE makecol(255,255,255)

//General Game Settings
int volume = 128;
int pan = 128;
int pitch = 1000;

#
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){


    allegro_init();
    atexit(&dumb_exit);//initialize dumb
    dumb_register_stdfiles(); //tELL DUMB HOW TO OPEN FILES

    install_keyboard();
    if(install_sound(DIGI_AUTODETECT, MIDI_NONE, "") != 0){

        allegro_message("error initializing the sound system");

    }


    set_color_depth(16);
    set_gfx_mode(GFX_AUTODETECT_WINDOWED, 1100, 550, 0, 0);

    write_status_screen("Status$>_Allegro Engine Initialization Successfull");
//******************************************************************************//
//*****************************************************************************//
//Write code below this line since allegro has been initialized//
    BITMAP *dragon;
    BITMAP *main_title, *main_menu;
    BITMAP *buffer;

    /*Menu music*/
   // load_sample("OG_MUSIC\\straight_outta_compton_menu.ogg");

    //Setup Audiostream for Main Menu Music//

    write_status_screen("Status$> Loading OG Music Stream: \"Straight Outta Compton.OGG\"");


    DUH *myduh;

    myduh = dumb_load_it_quick("OG_MUSIC\\straight_outta_compton_menu.ogg");

    AL_DUH_PLAYER *dp = al_start_duh(myduh, 2, 0,
                                  volume, 4096, 48000);;

//logg_get_stream("straight_outta_compton_menu.ogg", volume, pan, true);



    SAMPLE *menu_guntrigger = load_sample("OG_MUSIC\\gun_menu_choose.wav");


    /*Menu count*/
    int menct = 0;

    buffer = create_bitmap(1100, 480);

    textprintf_ex(screen, font, 0, 0, WHITE, 0, "Resolution = %ix%i ", SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H);

    dragon = load_bitmap("BITMAPS\\COMPTON_START_MENU_FADED_TWO.bmp", NULL);
    main_title = load_bitmap("BITMAPS\\OGM_TITLE.bmp", NULL);
    main_menu = load_bitmap("BITMAPS\\MAIN_MENU.bmp", NULL);


    write_status_screen("Status$>_Bitmaps loaded into memory!");
    write_status_screen("Status$> Loading OG Sound Effects......:");
    rest(650);



    rest(700);


    int frames_drawn = 0;

    while(!key[KEY_ESC]){



    /*Handle Controls First modulus 2 to make selection easier, every second frame, keypress is captured. DO NOT DO THIS FOR ACTUAL GAMEPLAY*/

        if(key[KEY_UP] && frames_drawn % 2 == 0){
            play_sample(menu_guntrigger, volume, pan, pitch, FALSE);
            menct--;
        } else if (key[KEY_DOWN] && frames_drawn % 3 == 0){
            play_sample(menu_guntrigger, volume, pan, pitch, FALSE);
            menct++;
        }
        if (menct > 3){
            play_sample(menu_guntrigger, volume, pan, pitch, FALSE);
            menct = 0;
        }else if (menct <0){
            play_sample(menu_guntrigger, volume, pan, pitch, FALSE);
            menct = 3;
        }
        rest(10);


        //Erase everything
        clear(buffer);

        //status box
        rectfill(screen, 0, 480, 1100, 483, WHITE);

        /*Draw the frame based on user input*/
        draw_sprite(buffer, dragon, 0, 0);
        draw_sprite(buffer, main_title, 315, 10);
        drawframe(buffer, main_menu, 485, 145, 332, 305, 0, 0, 4, menct);
        //blit(main_title, screen, 0, 0, 50, 50, 540, 96);
        //masked_blit(main_title, screen, 0, 0, 50, 50, 540, 96);

        //masked_blit(source, dest, framex, framey, x, y, width, height);

        textprintf_ex(buffer, font, 900, 470, WHITE, 0, "Written By: Kelvin Silva", bitmap_color_depth(screen));

        textprintf_ex(buffer, font, 0, 470, WHITE, 0, "Frames Drawn: %i", frames_drawn);

        blit(buffer, screen, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1100, 480);

        /*pollduh*/
        al_poll_duh(dp);
        /*Wait for vsync, rest a little, update framecount and prompt for more input*/
        vsync();
        frames_drawn++;
        rest(50);
    }

    write_status_screen("Status$>_Game Loop Ended...");

    clear_status_screen();
//NOTE NEED TO SETUP MEMORY DESTRUCTION


    destroy_bitmap(dragon);
    destroy_bitmap(main_title);
    destroy_bitmap(buffer);

    allegro_exit();

    return 0;
}
END_OF_MAIN()



d:\programs\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\..\..\..\libaldmd.a(alplay.o)||In function `al_start_duh':|
D:\Users\Kelvin_Silva\Downloads\dumb-0.9.3\dumb-0.9.3\src\allegro\alplay.c|48|undefined reference to `al_assert'|
D:\Users\Kelvin_Silva\Downloads\dumb-0.9.3\dumb-0.9.3\src\allegro\alplay.c|49|undefined reference to `al_assert'|
D:\Users\Kelvin_Silva\Downloads\dumb-0.9.3\dumb-0.9.3\src\allegro\alplay.c|62|undefined reference to `play_audio_stream'|
D:\Users\Kelvin_Silva\Downloads\dumb-0.9.3\dumb-0.9.3\src\allegro\alplay.c|69|undefined reference to `voice_set_priority'|
D:\Users\Kelvin_Silva\Downloads\dumb-0.9.3\dumb-0.9.3\src\allegro\alplay.c|74|undefined reference to `stop_audio_stream'|
d:\programs\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\..\..\..\libaldmd.a(alplay.o)||In function `al_stop_duh':|
D:\Users\Kelvin_Silva\Downloads\dumb-0.9.3\dumb-0.9.3\src\allegro\alplay.c|92|undefined reference to `stop_audio_stream'|
d:\programs\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\..\..\..\libaldmd.a(alplay.o)||In function `al_pause_duh':|
D:\Users\Kelvin_Silva\Downloads\dumb-0.9.3\dumb-0.9.3\src\allegro\alplay.c|103|undefined reference to `voice_stop'|
d:\programs\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\..\..\..\libaldmd.a(alplay.o)||In function `al_resume_duh':|
D:\Users\Kelvin_Silva\Downloads\dumb-0.9.3\dumb-0.9.3\src\allegro\alplay.c|113|undefined reference to `voice_start'|
d:\programs\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\..\..\..\libaldmd.a(alplay.o)||In function `al_duh_set_priority':|
D:\Users\Kelvin_Silva\Downloads\dumb-0.9.3\dumb-0.9.3\src\allegro\alplay.c|123|undefined reference to `voice_set_priority'|
d:\programs\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\..\..\..\libaldmd.a(alplay.o)||In function `al_poll_duh':|
D:\Users\Kelvin_Silva\Downloads\dumb-0.9.3\dumb-0.9.3\src\allegro\alplay.c|156|undefined reference to `get_audio_stream_buffer'|
D:\Users\Kelvin_Silva\Downloads\dumb-0.9.3\dumb-0.9.3\src\allegro\alplay.c|166|undefined reference to `free_audio_stream_buffer'|
D:\Users\Kelvin_Silva\Downloads\dumb-0.9.3\dumb-0.9.3\src\allegro\alplay.c|167|undefined reference to `stop_audio_stream'|
D:\Users\Kelvin_Silva\Downloads\dumb-0.9.3\dumb-0.9.3\src\allegro\alplay.c|179|undefined reference to `free_audio_stream_buffer'|
d:\programs\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\..\..\..\libaldmd.a(alplay.o)||In function `al_duh_encapsulate_sigrenderer':|
D:\Users\Kelvin_Silva\Downloads\dumb-0.9.3\dumb-0.9.3\src\allegro\alplay.c|208|undefined reference to `al_assert'|
D:\Users\Kelvin_Silva\Downloads\dumb-0.9.3\dumb-0.9.3\src\allegro\alplay.c|209|undefined reference to `al_assert'|
D:\Users\Kelvin_Silva\Downloads\dumb-0.9.3\dumb-0.9.3\src\allegro\alplay.c|215|undefined reference to `play_audio_stream'|
D:\Users\Kelvin_Silva\Downloads\dumb-0.9.3\dumb-0.9.3\src\allegro\alplay.c|222|undefined reference to `voice_set_priority'|
d:\programs\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\..\..\..\libaldmd.a(alplay.o)||In function `al_duh_decompose_to_sigrenderer':|
D:\Users\Kelvin_Silva\Downloads\dumb-0.9.3\dumb-0.9.3\src\allegro\alplay.c|248|undefined reference to `stop_audio_stream'|
||=== Build finished: 18 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|
```

Answer (score 0):

DUMB requires you to link with two libraries, the core libdumb and then the aldumb "glue". Looks like you are only linking with the latter. Order matters too.

Note that DUMB is used to play MOD files (and various variants). If you want ogg support, it comes built in Allegro 4.4 if you have the official ogg libraries installed.

Also, if you are just getting started, then you should really use Allegro 5. Version 4 isn't really supported any longer and doesn't work as well on modern operating systems.

Comment: well i try to add link to libdumb and libaldumb on codeblocks and same references errores are heppneings

Comment: `libaldmd.a` is unable to find the core Allegro library. Swap the order on the linker settings with it and `liballeg.a` (or whatever the name of the Allegro lib is ). The order is important with gcc.